# UPDATE SQL Statement with group by (using a self join) to the same table

Tags: sql-server

I have a sample data set

```
BookID Book_Name Book_Version_Number  New Book Version Number (Proposed)
1       XYZ      1.0000               1.0000
1       XYZ      1.0000               2.0000
2       ABC      1.0000               1.0000
2       ABC      1.0000               2.0000
2       ABC      1.0000               3.0000
```

So, I need incrementally and sequentially update the New Book Version Number grouped by the Title..

I need to put this an UPDATE SQL..My update seems to be failing as my group by clause is not working

Comment: Please post your query what have you tried

Answer (score 0):

You could use a cte and `row_number()`:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT BookId, 
           BookName, 
           Book_Version_Number,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY BookId ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) As rn
    FROM TableName
)

UPDATE CTE
SET Book_Version_Number = rn
```

Comment: Thank you Zohar for your quick turn around and help. ..Seems to be working so far. Will do a bit more spot checking. Ques though...Why did you use SELECT NULL ...Just trying to understand

Comment: Since you have no columns to sort by anyway, I prefer to use `order by (select null)` so that when you read the sql you know immidiatly that the order by is irrelevant.

Comment: OK Thanks. I slightly modified using ORDER BY BOOK_ID and it seemed to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to do this sort of thing using a [common table expression (cte)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx).

Using [**`row_number()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx):

```
;with cte as (
  select *
    , New_Book_Version_Number = row_number() over (
        partition by Book_Name /* Title */ 
        order by BookID
        )
  from Books
)
update cte
set Book_Version_Number = New_Book_Version_Number
```

If you want to preview the changes before running the update, just change the above to a `select` instead of an `update`. Note that only the first statement after the cte can use the cte.